# Merging n-lists of tuples at alternating indicies combination

Tags: python, tuples, combinations

I have a data container that is a list of lists of tuples. The minimum size of an incoming data container would be a list containing two sublists with each sublist containing two tuples of the form (x,y). The maximum incoming data size is a list with 100 sublists, with each sublist containing 2000 tuples of the form (x,y). However, I am trying to avoid hardcoding upper bounds into the function. Note that sublists will vary in tuple count.

The end goal is to take the sublists and merge them into a single ordered list of tuple of variable size depending on number of sublists.

**Example 1 with two sublists:**

```
a = [[(15,1),(14,2),(13,3),(12,4),(11,5),(10,6),(9,7),(8,8),(7,9),(6,10),(5,11),(4,12),(3,13),(2,14),(1,15)],
     [(7,1),(6,2),(5,3),(4,4),(3,5),(2,6),(1,7)]]
```

Would output (formatted for clarity):

```
[(15,1,7),
 (14,2,6),
 (13,3,5),
 (12,4,4),
 (11,5,3),
 (10,6,2),
 (9,7,1),
 (8,8,None),
     ...
 (1,15,None)]
```

**Example2 with three sublists:**

```
a = [[(7,1),(6,2),(5,3),(4,4),(3,5),(2,6),(1,7)],
    [(6,1),(5,2),(4,3),(3,4),(2,5),(1,6)],
    [(10,1),(9,2),(8,3),(7,4),(6,5),(5,6),(4,7),(3,8),(2,9),(1,10)]]
```

Would output

```
[(7,1,6,1,10),
(6,2,5,2,9),
(5,3,4,3,8),
(4,4,3,4,7),
(3,5,2,5,6),
(2,6,1,6,5),
(1,7,None,7,4),
(None,None,None,None,3)
    ...]
```

The output essentially follows the form:

For n-list > 2:

actually (x<sub>sublist 1</sub>,y<sub>sublist 2</sub>,x<sub>sublist 2</sub>,y<sub>sublist 2</sub>,x<sub>sublist n</sub>)

for n-list = 2:

(x<sub><sub>sublist 1</sub></sub>,y<sub><sub>sublist 1</sub></sub>,x<sub><sub>sublist n</sub></sub>)

I'm at a loss for how to start with this- all my attempts come for naught. Some ideas on how to approach it would be most appreciated.

Note: I have to use standard libraries only and python 2.7

Thanks

Comment: Your form states that for n-list > 2, out put is (x,y,x,y ,...) but the example 2 shows output to be (x,y,x) - or am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: Example one is for a list of two sublists, although my formatting is not great. Example two is for a list of 3 sublists. Example one output is (x,y,x) with the Y being the combined value for both tuple y. Example two output alternates the y value. And would continue to do so as the number of list increases. Let me recheck, maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: Also, why is the final ouput line from example 2 (3,8,None,None,None)? According to the pattern it should be `(None, None, None, None, 3)` ? And why does example2[6] flip the order of the final tuple?

Comment: The last line was an error on my part and I'll correct it.Transcribing from brain = errors.

Comment: @DanielleM. I made another error on how the output is formed. Its (x,y,x,y,x) where the y is all the same value from each tuple set and the x is the respective x values from each tuple set. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` library will let you do this with generators.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
a = ...    
longest = max(len(l) for l in a)
padded = (chain(l, repeat((None, None), longest - len(l))) for l in a[:-1])
last = chain(((x,) for x, y in a[-1]), repeat((None,), len(a[-1])))
result = [tuple(chain.from_iterable(input_tuples)) for input_tuples in zip(*chain(padded, (last,)))]
```

Here I use `repeat` to repeat the appropriate tuple of `None`s for the correct number of times. `chain` is used to string two or more generators together.

Edit: Simplified a little based on fact that all tuples have length 2, and added special cast for last sublist

Comment: This is a good answer, however for lists containing 2 sublists it outputs to the form of(x,y,x,y) rather than (x,y,x). and for lists greater than 2 sublists it should output to (x,y,x,y,x) rather than (x,y,x,y,x,y). Thank you though, I appreciate your perspective on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Oh I missed some details of your question so my answer is not correct, I'll amend it.

Comment: @SynchronizeYourDogma I've edited the code to have a special case for the last sublist.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm required to use Python 2.7x (per original post) so the unpacking * causes a problem.I'm working on a fix but I thought Id let you know in case you wanted to update your code here. thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Fixed it to work in python2.7 (just chained the padded and last together by making a length-1 tuple with last in it)

Comment: works beautifully! I'll give a little time in case anyone else wants to have a go and if not, I'll mark yours as the answer. Thank you for your help- I spent so much time thinking about it that i hit a wall.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[(7,1),(6,2),(5,3),(4,4),(3,5),(2,6),(1,7)],
    [(6,1),(5,2),(4,3),(3,4),(2,5),(1,6)],
    [(10,1),(9,2),(8,3),(7,4),(6,5),(5,6),(4,7),(3,8),(2,9),(1,10)]]

d = [dict(x) for x in a]

keys = set([y for x in d for y in x.keys()])

res=[]
for k in keys:
    temp=[]
    for x in d:
        temp.append(x.get(k))
        temp.append(k if x.get(k) is not None else None)
    res.append(temp[:-1])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[7, 1, 6, 1, 10]
[6, 2, 5, 2, 9]
[5, 3, 4, 3, 8]
[4, 4, 3, 4, 7]
[3, 5, 2, 5, 6]
[2, 6, 1, 6, 5]
[1, 7, None, None, 4]
[None, None, None, None, 3]
[None, None, None, None, 2]
[None, None, None, None, 1]]
```

Comment: While not in tuple output form  this does help me get past my blinders and tunnel vision.Thanks for your help

Comment: Potentially incorrect because dictionaries and sets don't guarantee maintaining order.